# Remove GNU Peppermint Linux loader

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bootable-media, gnu

Story:
I tried to do a full install of Linux Distro Peppermint 9 on a USB stick.
I went through the install process clicked custom and installed to the USB stick
I succeeded but not how I wanted.

I now have a laptop that goes into some GNU thing if the USB stick is not plugged in.
I assume this is some dual boot loader as when I plug the USB stick in it gives me the option Peppermint or Windows.

Help:
How can I remove this "GNU Loader" and always boot to Windows normally?
Is the USB stick I created Useable as a bootable media on any PC?

Any help appreciated!
-Peter

Comment: BIOS or UEFI?...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia UEFI I think in Disk management it has a EFI system partition.

Comment: Ok, I was kind of expecting that and those are good news. Just open the UEFI settings and change the boot order back to "Windows bootloader".

Comment: And again, do NOT use the commands in the answer.

Comment: Wow, that was extremely simple, I tried to go into the bios before but I was panicked and couldn't find the right key.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Do you mind making that as an answer as I can't give a comment the green tick thing. Thank you for your help -Peter

Comment: Done! You're welcome :) and yes, that's the beauty of UEFI. We're no longer dependent on a single bootloader saved in an obscure part of a drive. Bootloader are now stored in the EFI partition and many can coexist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove any bootloader.

Just open the UEFI settings and change the boot order back to "Windows bootloader" and it will boot Windows directly.

Booting with the USB stick plugged in should then boot to the Grub menu from which you can select one OS or the other. If not automatic then make sure to select the other bootloader instead of Windows.